# What test for a structural break in a VEC model?

Tags: change-point, vector-error-correction-model

Does anyone know which test to use for structural break in VEC model?

I thought to use a CUSUM AND CUSUM-sq, but it seems like CUSUM-sq always return results outside the critical bounds.

Any help greatly appreciated!

---

Actually, Im rather confused here. In many cases, where a VEC is applied in empirical work, the authors do not use tests for structural break and univariate tests for model specification i.e., test for normality, autocorrelation and so forth. Why is that so?